# Can't set device owner on Samsung device with Android 11

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-11, device-admin, device-owner

I'm trying to set my app as a device owner on the Samsung A51 with Android 11. It's a fresh device with no accounts added:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner <package>/<package>.receiver.AdminReceiver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package ComponentInfo{<package>/<package>.receiver.AdminReceiver} as device owner.
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:204)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:115)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:60)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:409)
```

There's an active built-in device admin:

```
adb shell dumpsys device_policy
Current Device Policy Manager state:
  
  
  
  Enabled Device Admins (User 0, provisioningState: 0):
    com.samsung.android.kgclient/.receiver.KGAdminReceiver:
      uid=10089
      testOnlyAdmin=false
```

This method works on other devices, but not on this Samsung. Why and how to fix it?

**P.S.** I've already read all (or almost all) similar topics on SO.

Comment: Did find the cause, or some solutions to do that?

Comment: @WaelAbo-Aishah not yet unfortunately

Comment: I have the same issue with Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e.
I have two such devices.
On one version 11, on the another 10 Android version. With version 10 it works as it should.

Comment: I think this is related with https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-11#work-company-owned

Comment: The only way is the official way now pushed by Samsung. You'll have to register with them, or use some 3rd party MDM that is partnering with Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot set your app as a device owner because your app not yet has device admin permission. You must set your app as a device admin, then you can set your app to be device owner. Use this command to set your app as a device admin.

```
adb shell dpm set-active-admin <package>/<package>.receiver.AdminReceiver
```

Then you can use your command to set your app as a device owner

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner <package>/<package>.receiver.AdminReceiver
```

It works for me ^^ you can try it.